# Nginx returning a 400 error when trying to point a new domain at an existing subdomain

Tags: nginx, dns

I have a domain running

```
http://www.exampledomain.com
```

and I have a subdomain that is working correctly at

```
http://mysub.exampledomain.com
```

both have web pages being served by nginx and I am able to hit both of those without a problem.

I have another domain that I want to point at that subdomain so it serves the same pages without redirecting the url.

```
http://www.myotherdomain.com
```

On that domain I setup these records

```
host name: www
ip address/url: mysub.exampledomain.com.
record type: CNAME (alias)

host name: @
ip address/url: mysub.exampledomain.com.
record type: CNAME (alias)
```

Now when I try to load http://www.myotherdomain.com I get a 400 error coming from nginx. Because it's an nginx error I'm assuming the dns is making it through but I could be wrong. Do I need to do something to let nginx or ubuntu be ok with serving requests from this domain? Modify my hosts file or something?

Edit: Now that it's been a little bit I'm no longer getting the error but It's loading the content of my first url. So using the psuedo domains above... www.myotherdomain.com is now loading the content of www.exampledomain.com instead of mysub.exampledomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by changing my record types from CNAMEs to URL frames. If anyone has more knowledge on the subject I would still love to know why my previous setup was causing nginx errors and this one isn't.